# google maps static api border coordinates

Tags: get, geolocation, maps, scale

I have a problem related to the Maps Static Api. I make a get request and it returns everything correctly, but I needed the geolocation of the edges of the map or the scale.

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-22,905425403246543,-43,16907657296473&zoom=15&size=400x400&key=**** ****&maptype=satellite`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi55B.png)

I need to know the geolocation of the edges of the map, or else the scale, because that way I would be able to reach the same result

I tried opening Google Maps and taking a printout with the scale and using this map, but it's laborious and doesn't work as it should.